# Execute jquery function by id when id is changed by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's possible to change an id of html balise with this function :

```
$("#test").attr('id', 'test2');
```

My exemple code is :

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $("#test").attr('id', 'test2');
    alert('test');
    return false;
});

$("#test2").click(function() {
    $("#test2").attr('id', 'test');
    alert('test2');
    return false;
});
```

The first function work normally but when the id is changed the second function is not run ...

Can you help me please ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you changing the ID? It doesnt work because the handler bound at runtime has no idea that `test` will become `test2` - you'd need event delegation to make this work.

Comment: Ok i will try to look event delegation and if i cant do this i will repost a new question :) thx

Comment: Maybe this is better: http://jsfiddle.net/1wpf60dj/ ?

Comment: something wrong in you page design if you need to switch ID's back and forth. why not toggle classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation:

```
$("body").on('click','#test2',function() {
 $("#test2").attr('id', 'test');
 alert('test2');
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is bound to the element itself, not it's attributes like `id` or `class`. So even if you change an attribute which you used to bind the event, the handler will remain with the element.

So in my opinion it's better to re-use the existing handler by condition checking. for example,

```
$("#test").click(function () {
  if (this.id == "test") {
    alert('test');
    this.id = 'test2';
  } else {
    alert('test2');
    this.id = 'test';
  }
  return false;
});
```

No need to bind extra handler to another element. This should be:

- faster (*No delay of bubbling*)
- memory efficient (*Less number of handlers*)

  when talking about complex `DOM` structure with hundreds of elements.